# Plot multiple lines (data series) each with unique color in R

Tags: r, colors, plot, unique, lines

I am fairly new to R and I have the following queries :

I am trying to generate a plot in R which has multiple lines (data series). Each of these lines is a category and I want it to have a unique color.

Currently my code is setup in this way :

First, I am creating an empty plot :

```
plot(1,type='n',xlim=c(1,10),ylim=c(0,max_y),xlab='ID', ylab='Frequency')
```

Then for each of my category, I am plotting lines in this empty plot using a "for" loop like so :

```
for (category in categories){
lines(data.frame.for.this.category, type='o', col=sample(rainbow(10)), lwd=2)
}
```

There are 8 categories here, and so there are 8 lines produced in the plot. As you can see, I am trying to sample a color from the rainbows() function to generate a color for each line.

However, when the plot is generated, I find that there are multiple lines which have the same color. For instance, 3 of those 8 lines have green color.

How do I make each of these 8 lines have a unique color ?

Also, how do I reflect this uniqueness in the legend of the plot ? I was trying to lookup the `legend()` function, however it was not clear which parameter I should use to reflect this unique color for each category ?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: YOu might want to change col=category, then you might see the different colours for each series. Can you give us sample data to work with ? ggplot2 can be a easier option for this.

Answer (score 91):

If your data is in [wide format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data#Wide) `matplot` is made for this and often forgotten about:

```
 dat <- matrix(runif(40,1,20),ncol=4) # make data
 matplot(dat, type = c("b"),pch=1,col = 1:4) #plot
 legend("topleft", legend = 1:4, col=1:4, pch=1) # optional legend
```

There is also the added bonus for those unfamiliar with things like `ggplot` that most of the plotting paramters such as `pch` etc. are the same using `matplot()` as `plot()`.
[image]

Comment: So nice when one creates data in the example itself in a simple way, rather than loading it from some unknown bundle of test data!

Answer (score 59):

If you would like a `ggplot2` solution, you can do this if you can shape your data to this format (see example below)

```
# dummy data
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, 9), val=sample(1:100, 45), 
                   variable=rep(paste0("category", 1:9), each=5))
# plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=val)) + geom_line(aes(colour=variable))
```

[image: ggplot2_geom_line]

Answer (score 38):

You have the right general strategy for doing this using base graphics, but as was pointed out you're essentially telling R to pick a random color from a set of 10 for each line. Given that, it's not surprising that you will occasionally get two lines with the same color. Here's an example using base graphics:

```
plot(0,0,xlim = c(-10,10),ylim = c(-10,10),type = "n")

cl <- rainbow(5)

for (i in 1:5){
    lines(-10:10,runif(21,-10,10),col = cl[i],type = 'b')
}
```

[image]

Note the use of `type = "n"` to suppress all plotting in the original call to set up the window, and the indexing of `cl` inside the for loop.

Comment: (Imo) a great solution for beginners in R :)

Comment: See my [alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629224/4581200) below that produces the same output using `lapply` instead of `for`

Comment: This answer could be made more complete by including a legend like [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860528/1048186).

Answer (score 23):

More than one line can be drawn on the same chart by using the `lines()`function

```
# Create the data for the chart.
v <- c(7,12,28,3,41)
t <- c(14,7,6,19,3)

# Give the chart file a name.
png(file = "line_chart_2_lines.jpg")

# Plot the bar chart.
plot(v,type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "Month", ylab = "Rain fall", 
   main = "Rain fall chart")

lines(t, type = "o", col = "blue")

# Save the file.
dev.off()
```

OUTPUT
[image]

Comment: How do you give a random color for each line? If I am adding lines in a for loop?

Answer (score 11):

I know, its old a post to answer but like I came across searching for the same post, someone else might turn here as well

By adding : colour in ggplot function , I could achieve the lines with different colors related to the group present in the plot.

```
ggplot(data=Set6, aes(x=Semana, y=Net_Sales_in_pesos, group = Agencia_ID, colour = as.factor(Agencia_ID)))
```

and

```
geom_line()
```

[image: Line Graph with Multiple colors]

Answer (score 8):

Using @Arun dummy data :) here a `lattice` solution :

```
xyplot(val~x,type=c('l','p'),groups= variable,data=df,auto.key=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @joran's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860261/4581200) using the base `plot` function with a `for` loop, you can **also use base `plot` with `lapply`**:

```
plot(0,0,xlim = c(-10,10),ylim = c(-10,10),type = "n")

cl <- rainbow(5)

invisible(lapply(1:5, function(i) lines(-10:10,runif(21,-10,10),col = cl[i],type = 'b')))
```

- Here, the `invisible` function simply serves to prevent `lapply` from producing a list output in your console (since all we want is the recursion provided by the function, not a list).

[image]

As you can see, it produces the exact same result as using the `for` loop approach.

So why use `lapply`?

Though `lapply` has been shown to perform faster/better than `for` in R (e.g., see [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/guess-who-wins-apply-versus-for-loops-in-r/); though see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42393658/4581200) for an instance where it's not), in this case it performs roughly about the same:

Upping the number of lines to 50000 for both the `lapply` and `for` approaches took my system `46.3` and `46.55` seconds, respectively.

- So, although `lapply` was just slightly faster, it was negligibly so. This speed difference might come in handy with larger/more complex graphing, but let's be honest, 50000 lines is probably a pretty good ceiling...

So the answer to "why `lapply`?": it's simply an alternative approach that works equally as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to add lines using `plot()`:

First, use function `par(new=T)`

option:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/kr_addat.html

To color them differently you will need `col()`.

To avoid superfluous axes descriptions use `xaxt="n"` and `yaxt="n"` 
 for second and further plots.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample code that includes a legend if that is of interest.

```
# First create an empty plot.
plot(1, type = 'n', xlim = c(xminp, xmaxp), ylim = c(0, 1), 
     xlab = "log transformed coverage", ylab = "frequency")

# Create a list of 22 colors to use for the lines.
cl <- rainbow(22)

# Now fill plot with the log transformed coverage data from the
# files one by one.
for(i in 1:length(data)) {
    lines(density(log(data[[i]]$coverage)), col = cl[i])
    plotcol[i] <- cl[i]
}
legend("topright", legend = c(list.files()), col = plotcol, lwd = 1,
       cex = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the x-axis is a factor / discrete variable, and one would like to keep the order of the variable (different values corresponding to different groups) to visualise the group effect. The following code wold do:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(45)

# dummy data
df <- data.frame(x=rep(letters[1:5], 9), val=sample(1:100, 45), 
                   variable=rep(paste0("category", 1:9), each=5))

# This ensures that x-axis (which is a factor variable)  will be ordered appropriately
df$x <- ordered(df$x, levels=letters[1:5])

ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=val, group=variable, color=variable)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + ggtitle("Multiple lines with unique color")
```

[image]
Also note that: adding group=variable remove the warning information: "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
the group aesthetic?"