# How to draw multiple lines on same plot in R?

Tags: r, line

I have have 4 linear equations. I used ?curve with par(plot=new) but it overwrites the lines instead of plotting parallel lines.

```
y<-2*x+1
y<-2*x+3
y<-(-2)*x+1
y<-(-2)*x+3
```

How can i plot these four lines on single plot to see the parallelogram on plot.?

Comment: Have you already checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860078/plot-multiple-lines-data-series-each-with-unique-color-in-r) and all of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+plot+multiple+lines)?

Comment: There is a `add` argument in `curve`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this maybe what you're looking for?
I just randomly generated X-values here.

```
set.seed(42);x<-rnorm(100)

plot(x,2*x+1,type="l",xlab="X",ylab="Y")
lines(x,2*x+3)
lines(x,(-2)*x+1)
lines(x,(-2)*x+3)
```

[image]

Comment: It works but when i use my data there only one line appears. a1<-61569627.5
b1<-1601
a2<-61569713.25
b2<-2139.5
a3<-61569843.25
b3<-2032.5
a4<-61569872.75
b4<-1820.5
m2<-(b3-b1)/(a3-a1)
m4<-m2
m1<-(b4-b2)/(a4-a2)
m3<-m1
set.seed(42);
x<-1:10;
plot(x,m1*(x-a1)+b1,type="l",xlab="X",ylab="Y")
lines(x,m2*(x-a2)+b2)
lines(x,m3*(x-a3)+b3)
lines(x,m4*(x-a4)+b4)

Comment: In order to include the other lines you need to set the `ylim` to include all the range of generated values by your models. As is shown in the answer below for instance. Note that in the data you gave in your comment some lines seem to be parallel and don't cross.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add xlim and ylim

```
limy=c(-4,4)
limx=c(-4,4)
curve(y<-2*x+1,xlim=limx,ylim=limy,ylab="")
par(new=T)
curve(y<-2*x+3,xlim=limx,ylim=limy,ylab="")
par(new=T)
curve(y<-(-2)*x+1,xlim=limx,ylim=limy,ylab="")
par(new=T)
curve(y<-(-2)*x+3,xlim=limx,ylim=limy,ylab="")
```

Answer (score 1):

With ggplot you could do something similar

```
x <- rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1)
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x,2*x+1)) + geom_line(aes(x,2*x+3)) etc
```