# Plotting one time series in different colors

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I want to plot a time series in different colors, e.g. that the first half is black and the second half of the series is red. I do this with

```
plot(1:10,col = c(rep("black",5),rep("red",5)),type="o")
```

However, it only changes the symbols but not the line: 
[image]

How can I also get a red line for the second half?

Comment: Do some internet search before posting here, this link works for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860078/plot-multiple-lines-data-series-each-with-unique-color-in-r

Comment: and where in the link is the question answered? I can plot n series in n colors but not one series in n colors.

Comment: One cannot plot one series in multiple colours, it has to be broken into parts with different colours. The same thing has been done in the answer below. The link then answers how to plot different lines with different colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply insert the different line segments manually like this:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, col = c(rep("black" ,5), rep("red" ,5)))

lines(1:5, 1:5, col = "black") 
lines(6:10, 6:10, col = "red")
```

[image: plot]

However, this approach is rather inflexible when it comes to more complex datasets. Therefore, I usually tend to use `xyplot` (from **lattice**) along with the `group`argument to accomplish such tasks. This would be a more flexible solution for your problem.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5))

library(lattice)
xyplot(x ~ 1:length(x), data = dat, group = y, type = "b", 
       col = c("black", "red"))
```

[image: xyplot]

Comment: Thanks. That was actually my own solution. I had hoped there was something more elegant.

Comment: Haha, I could have guessed so @HOSS_JFL. Have a look at the above update using groups in **lattice**. Maybe that's of any use to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1:10  #x can be any time series or vector

plot(x,type = 'l',col = 'black')

x2 = x

x2[1:5] = NA    #fill first half with NA

lines(x2,col = 'blue')   #NAs will be ignored in the plot
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please include the output from your code in the answer to illustrate the result?