# How do I plot this data using R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

```
> aggregate(dat[, 3:7], by=list(dat$TRT), FUN=mean)
  Group.1   DBP1  DBP2   DBP3   DBP4   DBP5
1       A 116.55 113.5 110.70 106.25 101.35
2       B 116.75 115.2 114.05 112.45 111.95
```

I wish to create a lines plot were the x-axis are the `names` (`DBP1`, `DBP2`, ..., `DBP5`).

It takes two seconds in Excel (I admit) and gives exactly what I want:
[image]

To be clear, the question is about getting the two rows of data into the plot, not about how they are displayed (i.e. with what line/point/color combination).

Comment: Not exactly, examples all only include ONE row of data, which I specifically added in my question

Comment: you can add another layer with command 'lines()'

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/index.html

Comment: why downvote, its obviously a struggle and far from obvious

Comment: @TMOTTM the answer is quite obvious if you consult `?plot`, specifically the information under the argument `type`

Comment: @GeneralAbrial Type "b" is just the graphical option for lines and points. It does not help with providing categorical arguments, nor does it help with adding two rows of data as separate data entries to plot. To be clear, I removed that part of the question and made it explicit. Still downvote?

Comment: Your edit happened after I left my comment, so I can't really be held accountable for reading what you hadn't yet written. I didn't downvote, although the tooltip for the downvote arrow states "this question does not show any research effort." Perhaps that's why?

Comment: near-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860078/plot-multiple-lines-data-series-each-with-unique-color-in-r

Comment: @BenBolker except that they're using numerical data as the x-argument, here it's categorical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `ggplot2`

**Data**

```
zz <- "Group.1   DBP1  DBP2   DBP3   DBP4   DBP5
A 116.55 113.5 110.70 106.25 101.35
B 116.75 115.2 114.05 112.45 111.95"

df <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)
```

**Load Required Packages**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

**Tidy**

```
df_tidy <- df %>% 
    gather(key, value, -Group.1)
```

**Plot**

```
ggplot(data = df_tidy, aes(x = key, y = value)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Group.1)) +
    ylim(90, 120)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: `group = Group.1` is unnecessary; the `colour` specification will set the grouping automatically is the colour-mapping uses a factor variable.

Comment: TIL. Changed to reflect.

Comment: no, you should leave `colour=Group.1` and drop `group=Group.1` (unless you want the two lines to be the same colour ...)

Comment: I don't think you are using `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

First step: use `melt` from the `reshape2` package:

```
d <- aggregate(
               dat[, 3:7],
               by=list(dat$TRT),
               FUN=mean
     )
m <- melt(d
     id="TRT",
     measure.vars=c("DBP1","DBP2","DBP3","DBP4","DBP5")
)
```

Then use

```
xyplot(m$value~m$variable, type="o", group=m$TRT, auto.key=list(TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simplest possible (??) base-R answer:

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
       Group.1   DBP1  DBP2   DBP3   DBP4   DBP5
       A 116.55 113.5 110.70 106.25 101.35
       B 116.75 115.2 114.05 112.45 111.95")
```

`matplot()` is the basic function for plotting multiple parallel sequences, but (1) it requires that the series be in *columns* of a matrix; (2) it can't handle character variables, so you have to drop the first column; (3) if you want the group names as axis labels, you have to add that with a separate `axis()` command. Unfortunately it's not (that I know of) possible to suppress just one of the axes, so you have to suppress them both (`axes=FALSE`), then add them both manually.

```
par(las=1) ## horizontal y-axis labels (cosmetic)
matplot(t(dd[,-1]),type="b",axes=FALSE,
        ylab="",ylim=c(90,120),
        col=c("red","blue"),pch=16,lty=1)
axis(side=2)                            ## y-axis (default labels)
axis(side=1,at=1:5,label=names(dd)[-1]) ## x-axis
box()                                   ## bounding box
legend("bottomleft",legend=dd$Group.1,
       col=c("red","blue"),lty=1,pch=16)
```

[image]

If you want to dispense with legend, nice tick-marks, etc., then just `matplot(t(dd[,-1]),...)` will do it.

Comment: Fine, the only thing I dont like about it is you're overwriting the axis indeces with the string indeces.

Comment: Can you clarify please? I thought that's what you wanted.  Or are you unhappy that it has to be done manually?

Answer (score 0):

A simple R code can be:

```
A <- c(116.55, 113.5, 110.70, 106.25, 101.35)
B <- c(116.75, 115.2, 114.05, 112.45, 111.95)

plot(A, type="n")
axis(1, at=1:5, labels=c("DBP1","DBP2","DBP3","DBP4","DBP5"))
lines(A, col="blue")
lines(B, col="red")
```

Alternate way:

```
plot(A, type="l", col="blue")
axis(1, at=1:5, labels=c("DBP1","DBP2","DBP3","DBP4","DBP5"))
lines(B, col="red")
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple approach is to custom your plot, step-by-step.

First, plot the first line and specify you don't when an x-axis to be drawn. Add the second line.
Add your custom x-axis with the labels you want.
Add points on the values you just plot.

Translate into `R` :

```
data <- matrix(c(116.55,113.5,110.7,106.25,101.35,116.75,115.2,114.05,112.45,111.95), nrow=2)

plot(data[1,], type="l", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:5, labels=c("DBP1","DBP2","DBP3","DBP4","DBP5"))
lines(data[2,])
points(data[1,])
points(data[2,])
```

the `xaxt="n"` specify that you want no x-axis text.

Here is a good reference : http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

[image]

Then, make it beautiful!

If you want a simpler approach for the future, here is a basic function you can improve

```
plot.Custom <- function(yy, xLabels, ...){
    plot(yy[1,], type="l", xaxt="n", ...)
    axis(1, at=1:dim(yy)[2], labels=xLabels)
    for(i in 1:dim(yy)[1]){
        lines(yy[i,])
        points(yy[i,])
    }
}
 plot.Custom(data, c("DBP1","DBP2","DBP3","DBP4","DBP5"))
```

Comment: I was honestly little struggling with using factor(x) on x-axis which didnt allow me do proper lines. You solution is great!

Comment: I can't believe there is not an easier way to do this since it's such a common task.

Comment: @TMOTTM there is. in the call to plot, set `type='b'`. or just read the documentation.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial +1 for `type="b"`. I've never used it. With it in head, the `matplot` function could be used : `matplot(t(data), type="b", pch="o", xaxt="n")`