# What are the performance differences between for-loops and the apply family of functions?

Tags: r, performance, lapply

It is often said that one should prefer `lapply` over `for` loops.
There are some exception as for example Hadley Wickham points out in his Advance R book.

(http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html) (Modifying in place, Recursion etc).
The following is one of this case.

Just for sake of learning, I tried to rewrite a perceptron algorithm in a functional form in order to benchmark 
relative performance.
source (https://rpubs.com/FaiHas/197581).

Here is the code.

```
# prepare input
data(iris)
irissubdf <- iris[1:100, c(1, 3, 5)]
names(irissubdf) <- c("sepal", "petal", "species")
head(irissubdf)
irissubdf$y <- 1
irissubdf[irissubdf[, 3] == "setosa", 4] <- -1
x <- irissubdf[, c(1, 2)]
y <- irissubdf[, 4]

# perceptron function with for
perceptron <- function(x, y, eta, niter) {

  # initialize weight vector
  weight <- rep(0, dim(x)[2] + 1)
  errors <- rep(0, niter)


  # loop over number of epochs niter
  for (jj in 1:niter) {

    # loop through training data set
    for (ii in 1:length(y)) {

      # Predict binary label using Heaviside activation
      # function
      z <- sum(weight[2:length(weight)] * as.numeric(x[ii, 
        ])) + weight[1]
      if (z < 0) {
        ypred <- -1
      } else {
        ypred <- 1
      }

      # Change weight - the formula doesn't do anything
      # if the predicted value is correct
      weightdiff <- eta * (y[ii] - ypred) * c(1, 
        as.numeric(x[ii, ]))
      weight <- weight + weightdiff

      # Update error function
      if ((y[ii] - ypred) != 0) {
        errors[jj] <- errors[jj] + 1
      }

    }
  }

  # weight to decide between the two species

  return(errors)
}

err <- perceptron(x, y, 1, 10)

### my rewriting in functional form auxiliary
### function
faux <- function(x, weight, y, eta) {
  err <- 0
  z <- sum(weight[2:length(weight)] * as.numeric(x)) + 
    weight[1]
  if (z < 0) {
    ypred <- -1
  } else {
    ypred <- 1
  }

  # Change weight - the formula doesn't do anything
  # if the predicted value is correct
  weightdiff <- eta * (y - ypred) * c(1, as.numeric(x))
  weight <<- weight + weightdiff

  # Update error function
  if ((y - ypred) != 0) {
    err <- 1
  }
  err
}

weight <- rep(0, 3)
weightdiff <- rep(0, 3)

f <- function() {
  t <- replicate(10, sum(unlist(lapply(seq_along(irissubdf$y), 
    function(i) {
      faux(irissubdf[i, 1:2], weight, irissubdf$y[i], 
        1)
    }))))
  weight <<- rep(0, 3)
  t
}
```

I did not expected any consistent improvement due to the aforementioned
issues. But nevertheless I was really surprised when I saw the sharp worsening 
using `lapply` and `replicate`.

I obtained this results using `microbenchmark` function from `microbenchmark` library

What could possibly be the reasons?
Could it be some memory leak?

```
                                                      expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq
                                                        f() 48670.878 50600.7200 52767.6871 51746.2530 53541.2440
  perceptron(as.matrix(irissubdf[1:2]), irissubdf$y, 1, 10)  4184.131  4437.2990  4686.7506  4532.6655  4751.4795
 perceptronC(as.matrix(irissubdf[1:2]), irissubdf$y, 1, 10)    95.793   104.2045   123.7735   116.6065   140.5545
        max neval
 109715.673   100
   6513.684   100
    264.858   100
```

The first function is the `lapply`/`replicate` function

The second is the function with `for` loops

The third is the same function in `C++` using `Rcpp`

Here According to Roland the profiling of the function.
I am not sure I can interpret it in the right way.
It looks like to me most of the time is spent in subsetting
[Function profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Nez.png)

Comment: Please be precise. I don't see any call to `apply` in your function `f`.

Comment: I'd suggest that you learn how to profile functions: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html

Comment: There's a couple errors in your code; first, `irissubdf[, 4] <- 1` should be `irissubdf$y <- 1`, so you can use that name later, and second, `weight` is not defined before you use it in `f`. It's also not clear to me that the `<<-` is doing the right thing in your `lapply` and `replicate` command, but it's not clear to me what it's supposed to be doing. This also may be a major difference between the two; the `<<-` has to deal with environments while the other does not, and while I don't know exactly what effect that might have, it's not quite an apples to apples comparison anymore.

Comment: Thanks to point out, I just forgot the copy the code to initialize weight( and weightdiff). I used <<- because the algorithm change the weight vector at each iteration, so the only solution I found was to update data in a vector in the caller environment

Comment: Hi, I tried out of curiosity to delete <<-. of course the code is now wrong but there is no performance improvement.
So the scope assignement is not the cause

Comment: 1. Your code doesn't run as written; you probably want `y` and not `irissubdf$y`. 2. Your code doesn't work as written; `f()` doesn't return the same result as `perceptron(*)`.

Comment: you are right, now is correct

Comment: Your code is still wrong.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

First of all, it is an already long debunked myth that `for` loops are any slower than `lapply`. The `for` loops in R have been made a lot more performant and are currently at least as fast as `lapply`.

That said, you have to rethink your use of `lapply` here. Your implementation demands assigning to the global environment, because your code requires you to update the weight during the loop. And that is a valid reason to not consider `lapply`.

`lapply` is a function you should use for its side effects (or lack of side effects). The function `lapply` combines the results in a list automatically and doesn't mess with the environment you work in, contrary to a `for` loop. The same goes for `replicate`. See also this question:

[Is R's apply family more than syntactic sugar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar)

The reason your `lapply` solution is far slower, is because your way of using it creates a lot more overhead.

- `replicate` is nothing else but `sapply` internally, so you actually combine `sapply` and `lapply` to implement your double loop. `sapply` creates extra overhead because it has to test whether or not the result can be simplified. So a `for` loop will be actually faster than using `replicate`.
- inside your `lapply` anonymous function, you have to access the dataframe for both x and y for every observation. This means that -contrary to in your for-loop- eg the function `$` has to be called every time.
- Because you use these high-end functions, your 'lapply' solution calls 49 functions, compared to your `for` solution that only calls 26. These extra functions for the `lapply` solution include calls to functions like `match`, `structure`, `[[`, `names`, `%in%`, `sys.call`, `duplicated`, ...
  All functions not needed by your `for` loop as that one doesn't do any of these checks.

If you want to see where this extra overhead comes from, look at the internal code of `replicate`, `unlist`, `sapply` and `simplify2array`.

You can use the following code to get a better idea of where you lose your performance with the `lapply`. Run this line by line!

```
Rprof(interval = 0.0001)
f()
Rprof(NULL)
fprof <- summaryRprof()$by.self

Rprof(interval = 0.0001)
perceptron(as.matrix(irissubdf[1:2]), irissubdf$y, 1, 10) 
Rprof(NULL)
perprof <- summaryRprof()$by.self

fprof$Fun <- rownames(fprof)
perprof$Fun <- rownames(perprof)

Selftime <- merge(fprof, perprof,
                  all = TRUE,
                  by = 'Fun',
                  suffixes = c(".lapply",".for"))

sum(!is.na(Selftime$self.time.lapply))
sum(!is.na(Selftime$self.time.for))
Selftime[order(Selftime$self.time.lapply, decreasing = TRUE),
         c("Fun","self.time.lapply","self.time.for")]

Selftime[is.na(Selftime$self.time.for),]
```

Comment: I'm very interested in any references for the claimed debunking in this answer. Can you please provide some here.

Answer (score 13):

There is more to the question of when to use `for` or `lapply` and which "performs" better. Sometimes ***speed*** is important, other times ***memory*** is important. To further complicate things, the ***time complexity*** may not be what you expect - that is, different behavior can be observed at different scopes, invalidating any blanket statement such as "faster than" or "at least as fast as". Finally, one performance metric often overlooked is **thought-to-code**, pre-mature optimization yada yada.

That said, in the [Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Repetitive-execution) the authors hint at some performance concerns:

> Warning: for() loops are used in R code much less often than in compiled languages. Code that takes a ‘whole object’ view is likely to be both clearer and faster in R.

Given a similar *use case*, *input* and *output*, disregarding *user preferences*, is one clearly better than the other?

###### Benchmark - Fibonacci sequence

I compare approaches to compute 1 to *N* [Fibonacci numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html) (inspired by the [benchmarkme](https://github.com/csgillespie/benchmarkme/blob/master/R/benchmark_programming.R) package), shunning the [2nd Circle](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) and ensuring that inputs and outputs for each approach are the same. Four additional approaches are included to throw some oil on the fire - a vectorized approach and `purrr::map`, and `*apply` variants `vapply` and `sapply`.

```
fib <- function(x, ...){
  x <- 1:x ; phi = 1.6180339887498949 ; v = \() vector("integer", length(x))
  bench::mark(
    vector = {
      y=v(); y = ((rep(phi, length(x))^x) - ((-rep(phi, length(x)))^-x)) / sqrt(5); y},
    lapply = {
      y=v(); y = unlist(lapply(x, \(.) (phi^. - (-phi)^(-.)) / sqrt(5)), use.names = F); y},
    loop = {
      y=v(); `for`(i, x, {y[i] = (phi^i - (-phi)^(-i)) / sqrt(5)}); y},
    sapply = {
      y=v(); y = sapply(x, \(.) (phi^. - (-phi)^(-.)) / sqrt(5)); y},
    vapply = {
      y=v(); y = vapply(x, \(.) (phi^. - (-phi)^(-.)) / sqrt(5), 1); y},
    map = {
      y=v(); y <- purrr::map_dbl(x, ~ (phi^. - (-phi)^(-.))/sqrt(5)); y
    }, ..., check = T
  )[c(1:9)]
}
```

Here is a comparison of the performance, ranked by median time.

```
lapply(list(3e2, 3e3, 3e4, 3e5, 3e6, 3e7), fib) # n iterations specified separately
N = 300
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
1 vector       38.8us   40.9us    21812.    8.44KB     0     1000     0     45.8ms
2 vapply        500us    545us     1653.    3.61KB     1.65   999     1      604ms
3 sapply        518us    556us     1725.   12.48KB     0     1000     0      580ms
4 lapply      513.4us  612.8us     1620.       6KB     8.14   995     5    614.2ms
5 loop        549.9us  633.6us     1455.    3.61KB     8.78   994     6    683.3ms
6 map         649.6us  754.6us     1312.    3.61KB     9.25   993     7    756.9ms

N = 3000
1 vector      769.7us  781.5us     1257.    82.3KB     1.26   999     1   794.83ms
2 vapply       5.38ms   5.58ms      173.    35.2KB     0.697  996     4      5.74s
3 sapply       5.59ms   5.83ms      166.   114.3KB     0.666  996     4      6.01s
4 loop         5.38ms   5.91ms      167.    35.2KB     8.78   950    50      5.69s
5 lapply       5.24ms   6.49ms      156.    58.7KB     8.73   947    53      6.07s
6 map          6.11ms   6.63ms      148.    35.2KB     9.13   942    58      6.35s

N = 30 000
1 vector       10.7ms   10.9ms      90.9     821KB    0.918   297     3      3.27s
2 vapply       57.3ms   60.1ms      16.4  351.66KB    0.741   287    13      17.5s
3 loop         59.2ms   60.7ms      15.9     352KB    16.7    146   154      9.21s
4 sapply       59.6ms   62.1ms      15.7    1.05MB    0.713   287    13      18.2s
5 lapply       57.3ms   67.6ms      15.1     586KB    20.5    127   173      8.43s
6 map          66.7ms   69.1ms      14.4     352KB    21.6    120   180      8.35s

N = 300 000
1 vector        190ms    193ms      5.14    8.01MB    0.206   100     4     19.45s
2 loop          693ms    713ms      1.40    3.43MB    7.43    100   532      1.19m
3 map           766ms    790ms      1.26    3.43MB    7.53    100   598      1.32m
4 vapply        633ms    814ms      1.33    3.43MB    0.851   100    39      45.8s
5 lapply        685ms    966ms      1.06    5.72MB    9.13    100   864      1.58m
6 sapply        694ms    813ms      1.27   12.01MB    0.810   100    39      48.1s

N = 3 000 000
1 vector        3.17s    3.21s    0.312     80.1MB    0.249   20    16       1.07m
2 vapply        8.22s    8.37s    0.118     34.3MB    4.97    20    845      2.83m
3 loop           8.3s    8.42s    0.119     34.3MB    4.35    20    733      2.81m
4 map           9.09s    9.17s    0.109     34.3MB    4.91    20    903      3.07m
5 lapply       10.42s   11.09s    0.0901    57.2MB    4.10    20    909       3.7m
6 sapply       10.43s   11.28s    0.0862   112.1MB    3.58    20    830      3.87m

N = 30 000 000
1 vector        44.8s   45.94s   0.0214      801MB   0.00854  10      4       7.8m
2 vapply        1.56m     1.6m   0.0104      343MB   0.883    10    850        16m
3 loop          1.56m    1.62m   0.00977     343MB   0.366    10    374      17.1m
4 map           1.72m    1.74m   0.00959     343MB   1.23     10   1279      17.4m
5 lapply        2.15m    2.22m   0.00748     572MB   0.422    10    565      22.3m
6 sapply        2.05m    2.25m   0.00747    1.03GB   0.405    10    542      22.3m

# Intel i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz / R version 4.1.1 / purrr 0.3.4
```

`for` and `lapply` approaches perform similarly, but `lapply` is greedier when it comes to memory, and a bit slower when the size of input increases (for this task). Note that `purrr::map` memory usage is equivalent to the `for-loop`, superior to that of `lapply`, in itself [a debated topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101045/why-use-purrrmap-instead-of-lapply). However, when the appropriate `*apply*` is used, here `vapply`, the performance is similar. But the choice could have a large impact on memory use, `sapply` being noticeably less memory efficient than `vapply`.

A peek under the hood reveals the reason of different performance for the approaches. The [for-loop](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/430360aa394b02046dd7175c0fc55e347e947f80/src/main/eval.c) performs many type checks, resulting in some overhead. [lapply](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/main/apply.c) on the other hand, suffers from a [flawed](http://janvitek.org/pubs/ecoop12.pdf) language design where lazy evaluation, or use of promises, comes at a cost, the source code confirming that the `X` and `FUN` arguments to `.Internal(lapply)` are promises.

Vectorized approaches are fast, and probably desirable over a `for` or `lapply` approach. Notice how the vectorized approach grows irregularly compared to the other approaches. However, aesthetics of vectorized code may be a concern: *which approach would you prefer to debug?*

Overall, I'd say a choice between `lapply` or `for` is not something the average R user should ponder over. Stick to what is easiest to write, think of, and debug or that is less (silent?) error prone. What is lost in performance will likely be canceled out by time saved writing. For performance critical applications, make sure to run some tests with different input sizes and to properly chunk code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

I did test the difference with a a problem that a solve recently.

Just try yourself.

In my conclusion, have no difference but for loop to my case were insignificantly more faster than lapply.

Ps: I try mostly keep the same logic in use.

```
ds <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol = 8))  
n <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')  
func <- function(ds, target_col, query_col, value){
  return (unique(as.vector(ds[ds[query_col] == value, target_col])))  
}  

f1 <- function(x, y){
  named_list <- list()
  for (i in y){
    named_list[[i]] <- func(x, 'a', 'b', i)
  }
  return (named_list)
}

f2 <- function(x, y){
  list2 <- lapply(setNames(nm = y), func, ds = x, target_col = "a", query_col = "b")
  return(list2)
}

benchmark(f1(ds2, n ))
benchmark(f2(ds2, n ))
```

As you could see, I did a simple routine to build a named_list based in a dataframe, the func function does the column values extracted, the f1 uses a for loop to iterate through the dataframe and the f2 uses a lapply function.

In my computer I get this results:

```
test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
1 f1(ds2, n)          100  110.24        1   110.112        0          0
  sys.child
1         0
```

&&

```
        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
1 f1(ds2, n)          100  110.24        1   110.112        0          0
  sys.child
1         0
```

Comment: Your script is not self-contained. Can you specify the `library()` for the `benchmark()` function and also define `ds2`?

Comment: your output is twice `f1`