# Do R programs always have an underlying C layer?

Tags: c, r, scripting-language

I have read that much of the functionality of R is done by C code that is called by R under the hood when an R program is run. Is this the case for every R program? Does this mean that every R statement is converted to C which is then compiled by a C compiler?

Comment: "Done by C code" is a loose and vague way of saying it that obscures some important points. There is certainly a runtime environment that executes natively on your machine, but how that runtime was created is not relevant at this point. It was probably translated from some high-level language like C, but that's not generally an observable part of the runtime. In other words, just because "someone wrote a C program to solve problem X" doesn't mean that problem X is intricately connected with C.

Comment: Granted R was written in C/C++. But that aside, even at run time, certain functions call C libraries. Does that mean these C libraries are already pre-compiled into 1s and 0s?

Comment: Yes. They're not "C libraries". They're just "libraries". You access them through some form of ABI or FFI, which may or may not borrow a style or vocabulary from C, but there's nothing fundamentally "C" about either the libraries or the runtime.

Answer (score 4):

It means that R is written in C or C++ (I don't know which) in the same way that your web browser is written in C or C++.  That doesn't mean web pages are converted to C and compiled with a  C compiler, and neither are R programs.

Comment: Exactly. Basically C, and some Fortran, and a bunch of R in its libraries.  C++ is supported for extensions but not used by R itself.

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to figure out if a simple R "for" loop is written in C, hard to search through R source code for that. I had an instructor tell me in case of a timing test not to use sapply because "it's written in C" but I would assume the for loop is implemented in C as well?

Comment: Actually, without providing proof, the [first line of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440872/3255525) makes a good case about speed of for vs. lapply in R