# Apply function of two elements

Tags: r, loops, apply

Let say I have a vector `x_n` of size n, and I want to apply a function to every element, except the first, that depends on the previous element f(x_i, x_(i-1)), how can this be done without looping?

Comment: Can we have some more info please?

Comment: Note that most of the times "without looping" is just a function that hides a loop inside of it..A reproducible example would help us understand better.

Comment: if `f` is vectorized, maybe `f(x[-1L], x[-length(x)])`?

Answer (score 0):

What about this? But as noted by @RLave `*apply` is just a loop in disguise:

```
my_fun<- function(i, x) {
    if(i == 1){
        return(x[i])
    } else {
        return(x[i] + x[i-1])
    }
}

x_n<- c(10, 20, 30, 40 ,50)

sapply(1:length(x_n), my_fun, x_n)
[1] 10 30 50 70 90
```

Comment: So there is no performance advantage in using apply? There is  not any sort of precompilation when you use it?

Comment: @ClaudioP No, I don't think there is much advantage. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393658/lapply-vs-for-loop-performance-r Basically, the main reason for using `*apply` is readability rather than speed.

Comment: I do get advantage in using sum or prod instead of looping though or it's false even for those?

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: I guess we are ot, but there is any difference between sum(x) and for( i in 1:length(x)){o=o+x[i]}?, My guess was that sum is an already compiled C function so should be faster.