# use apply instead of loop after replicating data

Tags: r

I am using this code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
      x1 = 'a'
      , x2 = 'b'
      , y = 0
)


df1 <- do.call("rbind", replicate(10, df1, simplify = FALSE))

for (row in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    df1[row,]$y = (row - 1) 
}

df1
```

Can this be improved by using an apply family function instead of the loop? Thanks!

Comment: Just `df1$y <- seq_along(df1$y) - 1`

Comment: Or `2:nrow(df1)`.

Comment: ok thanks all - maybe write an answer? thanks.

Comment: BTW - `apply` functions *are* loops

Comment: @dww - not sure what the point of your comment is ... but they are more efficient - hence my question ...

Comment: My point was that you seemed to be under the (common) misconception that apply is not a loop.  Moreover,  re. performance see, for example, ["Is R's apply family more than syntactic sugar?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2276001/2761575) and  ["it is an already long debunked myth that for loops are any slower than lapply"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440872/2761575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    x1 = 'a'
    , x2 = 'b'
    , y = 0
)


df1 <- do.call("rbind", replicate(10, df1, simplify = FALSE))


df1$y <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i)as.numeric(row.names(df1))[i]-1)
```

Comment: No need for `sapply` (which is a hidden loop). A vectorized solution is available. See comment above by @utubun.