# How to substitute multiple words with spaces in R?

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
drugs<-c("Lapatinib-Ditosylate", "Caffeic-Acid-Phenethyl-Ester", "Pazopanib-HCl", "D-Pantethine")

ads<-"These are recently new released drugs Lapatinib Ditosylate, Pazopanib HCl, and Caffeic Acid Phenethyl Ester"
```

What I wanted is to correct the drug names in `ads` with the names in `drugs` such that a desired output would be:

```
"These are recently new released drugs Lapatinib-Ditosylate, Pazopanib-HCl, and Caffeic-Acid-Phenethyl-Ester"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a vector of words to be replaced, then you can loop over that vector and the vector of words to replace them (`drugs`), replacing all instances of one element in each interation of the loop.

```
to_repl <- gsub('-', ' ', drugs)

for(i in seq_along(drugs))
  ads <- gsub(to_repl[i], drugs[i], ads)

ads
# "These are recently new released drugs Lapatinib-Ditosylate, Pazopanib-HCl, and Caffeic-Acid-Phenethyl-Ester"
```

Contrary to popular belief, `for`-loops in R are no slower than `lapply`

```
f_lapply <- function(ads){
  to_repl <- gsub('-', ' ', drugs)
  invisible(lapply(seq_along(to_repl), function(i) {
    ads <<- gsub(to_repl[i], drugs[i], ads)
  }))
  ads
}
f_loop <- function(ads){
  to_repl <- gsub('-', ' ', drugs)
  for(i in seq_along(to_repl))
    ads <- gsub(to_repl[i], drugs[i], ads)
  ads
}

f_loop(ads) == f_lapply(ads)
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f_loop(ads), f_lapply(ads), times = 1e4)
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq       max neval
#    f_loop(ads) 59.488  95.180 118.0793 107.487 120.205  7426.866 10000
#  f_lapply(ads) 69.333 114.462 147.9732 130.872 152.205 27283.670 10000
```

Or, using more general examples:

```
loop_over <- 1:1e5
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  for_loop = {for(i in loop_over) 1},
  lapply   = {lapply(loop_over, function(x) 1)}
  )
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#  for_loop  4.66174   5.865842   7.725975   6.354867   7.449429  35.26807   100
#    lapply 94.09223 114.378778 125.149863 124.665128 134.217326 170.16889   100

loop_over <- 1:1e5
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  for_loop = {y <- numeric(1e5); for(i in seq_along(loop_over)) y[i] <- loop_over[i]},
  lapply   = {lapply(loop_over, function(x) x)}
  )
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
#  for_loop 11.00184 11.49455 15.24015 12.10461 15.26050 134.139   100
#    lapply 71.41820 81.14660 93.64569 87.05162 98.59295 357.219   100
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using `lapply()` which will be faster than `for` loop. Modifying @IceCreamToucan's answer, this can be done in `lapply` as follows

```
to_repl <- gsub('-', ' ', drugs)

invisible(lapply(seq_along(to_repl), function(i) {
  ads <<- gsub(to_repl[i], drugs[i], ads)
}))

# [1] "These are recently new released drugs Lapatinib-Ditosylate, Pazopanib-HCl, and Caffeic-Acid-Phenethyl-Ester"
```

**Microbenchmark**

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
   lapply   80.514   87.4935  110.1103   93.304   96.1995 1902.861   100
 for.loop 2285.164 2318.5665 2463.1554 2338.216 2377.4120 7510.763   100
```

Comment: `lapply` is not faster than a `for`-loop. See the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393658/lapply-vs-for-loop-performance-r, or [this article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/)

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I have generally experienced that ‘lapply’ is faster than for loop.  Maybe not in the case of the example you provided.  But it is certainly faster here.

Comment: I wouldn't say "certainly", see my answer

Comment: This is interesting.