# R: Parent assignment operator in sapply

Tags: r, assign, sapply

Consider the two level list created by following code:

```
a = list()
s = seq(1,5)
for (i in s) {
  a[[i]] = list(field1 = i, field2 = letters[i])
}
```

Say I want to add a third element, "field3" to each sub-list, and do it with following combination of sapply(..) and the parent assignment operator:

```
sapply(s, function(x) a[[x]]$field3 <<- 5 - x)
```

Is this dangerous or considered abuse of the parent assignment operator?
What is the recommended alternative? Are there potential speed gains from using this sapply statement instead of a for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `for-loop`s in this context. It's clearer and `sapply` does not speed it up AFAIK, since `sapply` is just a special case of a `for-loop` under the hood. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393658/lapply-vs-for-loop-performance-r) for details.

e.g.:

```
for (i in s) a[[i]]$field3 <- 5 - i
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought one of the points of the *apply function family was to allow parallellization better than for-loops. Is the only benefit of *apply syntactical brevity?

Comment: @Anton: I added a link to a discussion on apply-functions and speed, see my edit

Comment: Thank you, excellent reference for speed discussions, which there seem to be a lot of now that I looked. Also, linked at top of that question is [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html) where Hadley points out a few cases where for-loops are recommended over *apply family, including one similar to the one I asked about.