# apply function to igraph object

Tags: r, function, networking, apply

I would like to learn how to code more efficiently using `apply`, `sapply` or `lapply`. While I understand the basics of it, I am yet lacking intuition. Specifically, I would like to use `apply` on a graph object. Is it possible to implement the example below with one of these functions and how could it be done? Any more efficient solution is welcome as the graph I am interested has more than 2 Mio. nodes, each having one edge.

```
# data
g <- make_graph(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6), directed = T)

# loop 
for(i in 1:length(V(g))){
  neigbours[[i]] <- adjacent_vertices(g, v= c(i), mode = "in")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply` is not necessarily more efficient. But you can improve efficiency by creating the object `neigbours` first, instead of extending it in each `for` loop iteration, forcing calls to R's memory management routins.

```
neigbours <- vector("list", length = length(V(g)))
for(i in 1:length(V(g))){
  neigbours[[i]] <- adjacent_vertices(g, v= c(i), mode = "in")
} 

neib2 <- lapply(seq_along(V(g)), function(i){
  adjacent_vertices(g, v = i, mode = "in")
})
all.equal(neigbours, neib2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I have been told, that for loops are less efficient than ```lapply``` and that I should consider learning ```lapply``` for this reason.

Comment: @SFront That statement is a [myth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393658/lapply-vs-for-loop-performance-r).

Comment: also comparing system.time() shows that lapply is indeed faster

Comment: @SFront Yes, but in my test it's only 5% faster.