# Creating a function looping over each row in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I want to write a function that creates a new column with rowmeans for Columns 1-3, **only if** **more than 2 questions for Columns 1-3 per row** were answered, otherwise print 'N'.

Here is my dataframe:

> `test <- data.frame(Manager1 = c(1, 3, 3), Manager2 = c(3, 4, 1), Manager3 = c(NA , 4, 2), Team1 = c(3, 4, 1))`

Desired output:

```
Manager1 Manager2 Manager3 Team1 mean_score
    1       3                3        N
    3       4        4       4     3.66667
    3       1        2       1        2
```

My code is as follows, but it's not working:

```
#create function
mean_score <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
    if (sum(test[i, x] != "NA", na.rm = TRUE) >2){
      test$mean_score[i] <- rowMeans(test[i, x], na.rm = TRUE)
    } else 
      test$mean_score[i] <- print("N")
  }
}

#compute function
mean_score(1:3)
```

What am I missing? Suggestions on better code are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not ideal to put a character together with a numeric value, since it will convert the whole column into character. However, if that is what you want:

```
my_sum <- function(x,min=2){
  s <- mean(x, na.rm = T) # get the mean
  no_na <- sum(!is.na(x)) # count the number of non NAs
  if(no_na>min){s}else{"N"} # return mean if enough non NAs
}
test$mean <- apply(test[,1:3],1,my_sum)

test

  Manager1 Manager2 Manager3 Team1             mean
1        1        3       NA     3                N
2        3        4        4     4 3.66666666666667
3        3        1        2     1                2

str(test)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Manager1: num  1 3 3
 $ Manager2: num  3 4 1
 $ Manager3: num  NA 4 2
 $ Team1   : num  3 4 1
 $ mean    : chr  "N" "3.66666666666667" "2"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is best to avoid characters with numeric in the same column! If we were to use numeric values, would it just be else {NA}? Also, would you recommend apply over for loops?

Comment: yes, you can just add NA instead of "N". I think the apply version is less cumbersome and easier to read. There are plenty of posts about loops vs the apply family on this website. Here you find one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393658/lapply-vs-for-loop-performance-r

Answer (score 1):

You simply can use `rowMeans` what will return `NA` if there is one row holding `NA` what should be here equivalent to *only if more than 2 questions for Columns 1-3 per row were answered*.

```
test$mean_score <- rowMeans(test[,1:3])
#  Manager1 Manager2 Manager3 Team1 mean_score
#1        1        3       NA     3         NA
#2        3        4        4     4   3.666667
#3        3        1        2     1   2.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

While GKi has a better answer that's more simple and that you should use here is what I changed your code to be so that it works.

Generally when making a function you want to have the input be the dataframe, in this case `text` and changing the function from there.

Another important thing of note is you probably want to make a vector of values first and then attach said vector to the dataframe as I do in the code below, but you need to make sure you create an empty vector object to do so. R doesn't really let you slowly add cell data to a dataframe, it prefers that a vector (which can be added to) of equal length be joined to it.

Also you don't need to use `print()` to insert a character into a vector either.

Hope this helps explain why your function was having issues, but frankly GKi's answer is better for general R use!

```
mean_score <- function(x) {
  mean_score <- vector()
  for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    if (sum(x[i,] != "NA", na.rm = TRUE) >3){
      mean_score[i] <- rowMeans(x[i,], na.rm = TRUE)
    } else 
      mean_score[i] <- "N"
  }
  x$mean_score <- mean_score
  return(x)
}

mean_score(test)
```

Comment: Is that in regards to the redundancy of the function name and the vector name `mean_score`? Guess that's not best practice, but the code worked for me so I'm not sure what you're pointing out?

Comment: Sorry my mistake I ran the code and it failed I realise I was reading the wrong `test`. Will delete my comment.