# How to assign 0 to the minimum values by row in a matrix (in a fast/efficient way)?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, matrix

One has a matrix `Lambda` with `p` columns and `n` rows and for each row wants assign all the values to `0` except the value in the first column and the maximum of the values in the other columns (in that sense all the `p - 2` minimum values after avoiding the first column).

For the moment I am doing this with a `for` loop, like follows:

```r
set.seed(60)
(Lambda = matrix(sample.int(30),5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   19   20   27   18   15   25
[2,]   16   28    1    4   22    7
[3,]    2   10    8   23    3   12
[4,]    5    6    9   17   11   29
[5,]   26   30   24   13   14   21

m <- ncol(Lambda) - 2
for(ir in seq_len(nrow(Lambda))){
    Lambda[ir, match(tail(sort(abs(Lambda[ir, 2:ncol(Lambda)]), decreasing = TRUE), m), Lambda[ir,])] <- 0
}
Lambda
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   19    0   27    0    0    0
[2,]   16   28    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    0    0   23    0    0
[4,]    5    0    0    0    0   29
[5,]   26   30    0    0    0    0
```

Fine, one gets the goal, but if there were many rows it would become a problem. Is there a solution not using a `for` loop? It could be with `lapply` but I'm not sure if it would be really efficient. Maybe with `data.table` after converting the matrix?

Thank you!

Comment: How big is the actual matrix you are going to use this one?

Comment: Actually my matrix is not so big (any case, less than 1 million rows). It is not a problem for me but I would prefer to solve this question in a better  way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized version that can think of:

```
vectorized <- function(Lambda) {
  max <- matrixStats::rowMaxs(Lambda, cols = -1)
  noreplace <- sweep(Lambda, 1, max, "==")
  noreplace[, 1] <- TRUE
  Lambda * noreplace
}
```

But it is not faster than the for loop by @Vandenman.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great. Actually, benchmarks with the size of the one by sindri_baldur or bigger, tell that your function is almost as faster as `foo2` by him and markus

Answer (score 3):

So concerning

> Is there a solution not using a for loop.

For some algorithms, you just have to write a for loop. And that's okay! Swapping a for loop for something like lapply is not really a performance improvement (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440872/4917834).

It is possible to speed up your code though:

```r
# your example
set.seed(60)
Lambda = matrix(sample.int(30),5)

original <- function(Lambda) {
  m <- ncol(Lambda) - 2
  for (ir in seq_len(nrow(Lambda))){
    Lambda[ir, match(tail(sort(abs(Lambda[ir, 2:ncol(Lambda)]), decreasing = TRUE), m), Lambda[ir,])] <- 0
  }
  Lambda
}
original(Lambda)

# a faster alternative
proposal <- function(Lambda) {

  nc <- ncol(Lambda)
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(Lambda))) {
    m <- which.max(abs(Lambda[i, -1L]))
    Lambda[i, (2:nc)[-m]] <- 0
  }
  Lambda
}
proposal(Lambda)
```

Let's benchmark the two approaches:

```r
bch <- bench::mark(
  original(Lambda),
  proposal(Lambda)
)
summary(bch, relative = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression              min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc 
  <bch:expr>            <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> 
1 original(Lambda)       25.7   24.1       1           1     1     1447     4
2 proposal(Lambda)        1      1        23.6         1     2.57  9997     3
```

So `proposal` is about 24 times faster than your original solution (median time for original is 313.8µs, for proposal it's 13.1µs). If that's not fast enough it might be worthwhile to look for a package that has implemented this in C or C++. I played around with `matrixStats` but no luck. Alternatively, you could port this to C++ with `Rcpp` which should also speed up the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's already a great improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option that <s>is more than 15%</s> seems a bit faster than `proposal()` on 600k rows:

```
foo <- function(Lambda) {
  nr <- nrow(Lambda)
  keep <- c(seq_len(nr), apply(Lambda[, -1], 1, which.max)*nr + seq_len(nr))
  replace(Lambda, -keep, 0L)
}
```

*Edit*

A vast improvment is replacing the `apply()` + `which.max()` combo with `max.col()` as suggested by markus:

```r
foo2 <- function(Lambda) {
  nr <- nrow(Lambda)
  keep <- c(seq_len(nr), max.col(Lambda[, -1], ties.method = "first")*nr + seq_len(nr))
  replace(Lambda, -keep, 0L)  
}
```

(Updated) Benchmark:

```r
set.seed(60)
Lambda = matrix(sample.int(36e5), ncol = 6)
bench::mark(
  foo(Lambda),
  proposal(Lambda),
  foo2(Lambda),
  relative = TRUE
)[1:5]

  expression         min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>       <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 foo(Lambda)       17.7   12.1      1.09      3.67
2 proposal(Lambda)  19.3   13.1      1         1   
3 foo2(Lambda)       1      1       13.5       3.75
```

Comment: Your already good approach can be further improved if you use `max.col(Lambda[,-1], ties.method = "first")` instead of `apply(Lambda[, -1], 1, which.max)`

Comment: @markus wow the difference is night and day. Thank you, I had forgot about `max.col()`.

Comment: Thank you very much both sindri_baldur and @markus.