# Force R to write loop output to list after each iteration

Tags: r, for-loop

I am looping over a large list of shape files (xy-coordinates) that I want to store in another list in R after applying some functions to the shape.

```
list_adj <- list()
for(ii in 1:length(data_list)) {

  ij <- names(data_list)[ii]
  M <- data_list[[ii]]

  fancy_obj <- function(){do_fancy_things}

  list_adj[[ij]] <- fancy_obj

  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

The problem I am facing is that R keeps looping over all shape files without writing them to list_adj variable after each iteration. Instead, R tries to write all 1600 shape files to the list after all iterations are completed. This causes my for loop to crash all the time. Is there a way to force R to write to list after each iteration?

Comment: Are the 1.6k files bigger than your memory? Do you want to process the first few files while loading others in parallel? Does it take minutes to hours to run everything? If so, I recommend [R targets](https://docs.ropensci.org/targets/)

Comment: No, but Rstudio shows that memory peaks around 4 GB during the loop. Still crashes though. If I run the loop with a subset of data the loop works just fine.

Comment: Does it crash just because you run out of memory? Do you have just a 4GB machine? The operating system will kill processes wanting too much memory.

Comment: I have 8 GB but 4 GB seems to be the maximum amount that is allocated to R. It takes about 10 minutes to run the loop.

Comment: Please add some samples and expected output to the post. This loop seems memory inefficient, based on a prior benchmark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393658/lapply-vs-for-loop-performance-r/70023363#70023363 it could be rewritten to a `purrr::map` oneliner or itself be made more efficient, solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map` function instead of loop:

Data:

```
data_list <- list(sf1 = structure(list(geometry = structure(list(structure(c(2.3111662, 
48.840346), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 2.3111662, ymin = 48.840346, 
xmax = 2.3111662, ymax = 48.840346), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "WGS84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor", .Names = character(0)), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), sf2 = structure(list(geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(2.36571460340002, 2.3655857662182, 2.36547329046861, 
    2.36542516193229, 2.36528545258358, 2.36512653636567, 2.3648060350023, 
    2.36424260145439, 2.36387560297359, 2.36366713159424, 2.36334443947327, 
    2.36322695208547, 2.36317764205549, 2.36318437079076, 2.36321528700506, 
    2.36326729012258, 2.36331020083956, 48.8776400092826, 48.8774711513306, 
    48.8773023799338, 48.8772238828371, 48.8770522688551, 48.8768904454866, 
    48.8765622871995, 48.8759189703608, 48.8754916354644, 48.8752575997409, 
    48.8748871565497, 48.874683281842, 48.8744788703593, 48.8742630655848, 
    48.8740761681905, 48.8739487391069, 48.8738959065238), .Dim = c(17L, 
    2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 2.36317764205549, 
ymin = 48.8738959065238, xmax = 2.36571460340002, ymax = 48.8776400092826
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 1L, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor", .Names = character(0))))
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
list_adj <- map(1:length(data_list), function(x) data_list[[x]] %>%
                  st_crs()) # Replace st_crs() by anything, that is for the example.

names(list_adj) <- map(1:length(data_list), function(x) names(data_list)[[x]])
```

Output:

```
$sf1
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: WGS84 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]

$sf2
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: WGS84 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Comment: Thank you MonJeanJean. I can confirm that this works with my data. I find the use of the map function not very intuitive but I will get used to it. ;) thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 0):

[R targets](https://docs.ropensci.org/targets/) allows you to read files and apply R functions on them. It will process one file by the other and does not load everything into one big R list which might lead to out of memory errors:

1. Create a file `_targets.R`:

```
# load all libraries needed to read and process the shapefiles
library(targets)
library(sf)

# do fancy things
modify_shape <- function(x) {
  x
}

list(
  tar_target(
    shape_files, {
      list.files(pattern = ".shp$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
    },
    format = "file"
  ),
  tar_target(
    raw_shapes, {
      read_sf(shape_files)
    },
     pattern = map(shape_files)
  ),
  tar_target(
    processed_shapes, {
      modify_shape(shape_files)
    },
     pattern = map(raw_shapes)
  ),
)
```

2. Run the pipeline

```
tar_make()
```

3. load the result

```
tar_load(processed_shapes)
processed_shapes
```