# How can I optimize this for loop to run faster using lapply and parallelization?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, survival-analysis, mclapply

I am working on a mediation analysis using survival analysis techniques. This requires bootstrapping using a for loop. My challenge is that this model will take a long time to run and I would like to optimize it if possible. I have heard turning this into an lapply will be helpful or parallelizing this code may be helpful as well.

This is my code below. You can ignore system.time.

```
system.time(
        
        for(i in 1:ntrials-1) {
                ntrials <- 10000
                npat <-4413
                sampledata<-mgfipdma1[sample(nrow(mgfipdma1),npat, replace=TRUE),]
                direct <- fixef(coxme(Surv(deathcont/365.25,dth)~ sex + gf + agec10 + ht + smk + diab + offpump + gsum + agsum + statin + LAD + seq + (1|trial), data= mgfipdma1))
                total <- coxs <- fixef(coxme(Surv(deathcont/365.25,dth)~ sex + agec10 + ht + smk + diab + offpump + gsum + agsum + statin + LAD + seq + (1|trial), data= mgfipdma1))
                indirect2 <-exp(total-direct)
                indirect<-rbind(indirect, indirect2)
        }
)

quantile(indirect, c(0.025, 0.50, 0.975))
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions you can provide.

So far, I have tried various mediation packages like mediate, lavaan, but none have been able to work with a mixed effects cox proportional hazards model with covariates like the one I am using (as far as I have been able to tell). As a result, I am using this for loop but it takes a significant amount of time to run (weeks for 10k iterations). I'm just wondering if there is any way I can optimize my code to speed up this process without needing to use the cloud.

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a short, representative sample of your data. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of the `dput(data)` command (preferred) or in tab delimited form. This will help users here answer your question.

Comment: (1) `1:ntrials-1` is going to be a vector starting at 0; even though you are not using `i`, it still makes a difference, since that vector will be `ntrials`-length, whereas what is often meant in this use is `1:(ntrials-1)`, which will be 1 shorter than `ntrials`.

Comment: (2) Iteratively adding rows to a matrix or dataframe using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: (3) You overwrite `ntrials` each time in your loop, this is doing nothing. Even if you were trying to _change_ the number of iterations by dynamically changing `ntrials` mid-`for`-loop, it doesn't do that: the value of `ntrials` current when the `for (..)` expression was evaluated is what is used, after that the `1:ntrials` has already been expanded and no longer dynamic. (Perhaps you mean to define `ntrials` and `npat` _before_ the `for`-loop? That would make more sense, though it had to have failed at least once ...)

Comment: There used to be performance issues with the `for` loop that have since been resolved. Generally, [there isn't much of a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70023363/6382434) between `lapply` and `for`, but you could benchmark for your specific situation to double check. I would not expect you to gain much for using one or the other. Instead, optimizing your code with some suggestions here and parallel processing would definitely help.

Comment: The [`foreach`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html) package could be a good place to start and has a very user friendly API.

Comment: If the model is slow to fit (> a few seconds), the details of the code around it (`for` vs `lapply`, using `rbind` etc) are probably not going to matter. Parallelization on the other hand will likely be very effective. For most use cases, 1000 bootstrap iterations should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

To parallelize tasks You may use **mclapply** from **parallel** package.

Your code may be like the following:

```
library(parallel)

ncores <- detectCores()
indirect <- mclapply(1:ntrials-1, 
             function(i){
               ntrials <- 10000
               npat <-4413
               sampledata<-mgfipdma1[sample(nrow(mgfipdma1),npat, replace=TRUE),]
               direct <- fixef(coxme(Surv(deathcont/365.25,dth)~ sex + gf + agec10 + ht + smk + diab + offpump + gsum + agsum + statin + LAD + seq + (1|trial), data= mgfipdma1))
               total <- coxs <- fixef(coxme(Surv(deathcont/365.25,dth)~ sex + agec10 + ht + smk + diab + offpump + gsum + agsum + statin + LAD + seq + (1|trial), data= mgfipdma1))
               indirect2 <-exp(total-direct)
               return(indirect2)
             }, mc.cores = ncores)

indirect <- do.call(rbind, indirect)
```