# Why does apply seem to drop the CRS?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

The title really sums up my question. Apply seems to drop the CRS, but other functions don't. What is the best way to calculate a geographic function on a vector of points?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# Generate 1000 lat longs, save as sf, and set crs
df1 <- data.frame(lat = runif(1000, 30, 33.4), long = runif(1000, -95, -82)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"),
           crs = 4326)

# Single point, with identical crs
df2 <- data.frame(lat = 32, long = -96) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"),
           crs = 4326)

apply(df1, 1, function(x) st_distance(x, df2))
```

This gives the error: `Error in st_distance(x, df2) : st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE`

But these both work fine:

```
st_distance(df1[1,], df2)

final.df <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  ith.distance <- st_distance(df1[i,], df2)
  
  final.df <- rbind(final.df, ith.distance)
}
```

The for loop is certainly not the most efficient way to do this. ...Is it??

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that `for` is any slower than `apply`, you [might be surprised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440872/10781678)... Although, upon re-reading, the copy-on-modify you do by growing `final.df` in-place is going to hurt performance.

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: Just in case, you do know that `st_distance()` handles this case directly, as in `st_distance(df1, df2)`  returns 1000x1 distance matrix?

Comment: and for simple cases like this you don't need `sf` to calculate the distances, you can use the performant `geodist::geodist(, measure = "haversine")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Points:

1. `for` and `apply` loops have no real difference in performance, that's an old condition (it used to be true) that was fixed many years ago. For the most part, the decision to use one over the other should be made on data-wrangling and proficiency reasons, not "speed". Typically when there are problems with `for`-loop performance, it has everything to do with what is done inside the loop, and nothing to do with `for` itself.
2. Iteratively calling `final.df <- rbind(final.df, ith.distance)` is going to perform very poorly in the long haul. With each iteration, it makes a complete copy of all data; this is fine when you have a few rows, but as you get into the 100s and 1000s, it takes just a little bit more time each pass through the loop. Don't do this, it's better to append the results to a `list` and do a single call to `rbind`. I'll demonstrate this later.
3. It is generally more efficient to loop over the *smaller* of the frames; in this case, that would be `df2` instead of `df1`. (Perhaps this is just a matter of the sample data you generated, but I'm saying it in case.)

I suggest iterating over row numbers and doing your distance calculation that way.

```r
### iterating over the LARGER frame
system.time(res1 <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(rn) as.numeric(sf::st_distance(df1[rn,], df2))))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.782   0.000   4.783 

### iterating over the SMALLER frame
system.time(res2 <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df2)), function(rn) as.numeric(sf::st_distance(df1, df2[rn,]))))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.008   0.000   0.009 

identical(res1, c(res2))
# [1] TRUE
head(res1)
# [1]  974915.8  184703.5 1215753.1  260598.1 1063713.6  745808.6
head(res2)
#           [,1]
# [1,]  974915.8
# [2,]  184703.5
# [3,] 1215753.1
# [4,]  260598.1
# [5,] 1063713.6
# [6,]  745808.6
```

`res1` is a vector, `res2` is a matrix (1 column), and the values are identical. The latter ran much faster, this is the results of using R's vectorized calculations when available (and they are here).

For the record, here is a `for` loop but avoiding the per-pass `rbind`.

```r
lst1 <- list()
system.time({
  for (rn in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    dist <- sf::st_distance(df1[rn,], df2)
    lst1 <- c(lst1, list(dist))
  }
  lst1 <- do.call(rbind, lst1)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.717   0.000   4.717 

lst2 <- list()
system.time({
  for (rn in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    dist <- sf::st_distance(df1, df2[rn,])
    lst2 <- c(lst2, list(dist))
  }
  lst2 <- do.call(rbind, lst2)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.010   0.000   0.011 

identical(lst1, lst2)
# [1] TRUE
identical(res2, lst2)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

As to why `apply` doesn't work: let's look at what is provided internally:

```r
apply(df1, 1, function(x) {browser();1;})
Browse[1]> debug at #1: [1] 1
Browse[2]> x
$geometry
POINT (-85.94798 30.29108)
```

If you look at the start of `apply` ([`src/library/base/R/apply.R#29`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/apply.R#L29)), one of the first things it does is convert the input to a `matrix`:

```r
    ## Ensure that X is an array object
    dl <- length(dim(X))
    if(!dl) stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")
    if(is.object(X))
    X <- if(dl == 2L) as.matrix(X) else as.array(X)
###                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^  this is a problem for sf-objects
```

Among other things, this strips the CRS from the `"sf"`-class object.

(For the record, this call to `as.matrix(X)` is also a problem when doing row-wise operations on a frame with mixed `character` and non-string columns; if `X` is not sufficiently subsetted before `apply`, then all values may be converted to strings.)

Comment: Super detailed, and even helped me with bad coding practices. Much appreciated!