# Plotting Multiple Series In R

Tags: r

I have a data set in which, for each day in the work week (Monday - Friday), I have a value that belongs to a category. In table form, it looks like this:

```
cat | day | value
 A  |  0  | 1
 A  |  1  | 0
 A  |  2  | 2
 A  |  3  | 1
 A  |  4  | 3
 B  |  0  | 0
 ...and so on...
```

Every category has a value for days 0-4.

What I would like to do is plot each category as a separate line (on the same plot), where the x values are the days, and the y values are the values for each day. How can I accomplish this in R?

Comment: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(dat, aes(day, value, colour=cat)) + geom_line() + geom_point()`, where `dat` is your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward to do with the `ggplot2` library as mentioned in the comments, and you can do this by setting an aesthetic like `colour` on your category variable but in order to have distinct lines for each of your categories without specifying other aesthetics, you need to use the `group` aesthetic. There is extensive documentation [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html).

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data_frame(category = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), 
              day = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), 
              value = c(1,0,2,1,3,2,1,3))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = day, y = value, colour = category, group = category)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Furthermore, this is probably a duplicate of [Plot multiple lines (data series) each with unique color in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860078/plot-multiple-lines-data-series-each-with-unique-color-in-r?rq=1).