# How to plot multiple rows into single graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I am trying to figure this out but I am having trouble.

I am trying to plot this data but I"m not sure how to even begin. I read other posts about using ggplot2 put then I am not sure if I have to write a different column for every FundID. Also I am curious how I format my data to "long format" for ggplot2.

#I have tried this
`plot(filename,type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Amount",
main = "Amount over time")

#But I get this error which I don't understand
Error in plot.default(...) :
formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments

My goal is to plot my data as a time series line graph and have each FundID have its own color. Something like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860078/plot-multiple-lines-data-series-each-with-unique-color-in-r). The 1-8 at the top are the periods and I want to create a graph with the periods 1-8 on the x-axis and the numbers on a scale from 0-100 on the y-axis. I have attached my data for reference. Thank you in advance!

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot your data to long form. You can do that with the `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-FundID, names_to = "x", values_to = "y") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = FundID)) + 
  geom_line()
```